# 3.5mm Audio Jack - No Black Insulating Ring

Tags: headphones, hardware

The 3.5 mm audio jack on my headphones (Beyerdynamic DT 770 Pro 32 Ohms) got bent but I straightened it and it was working. The problem is that now I have to turn the jack around in the 3.5mm plug to find the "sweet spot" otherwise there is no sound in the right can.

Is this because of the party missing black insulating ring? If I get the ring replaced at a local electric shop then is it going to work fine?

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insulation ring itself being absent shouldn't cause problems, as long as the Ring and Sleeve contacts on the jack don't touch each other.

I suspect the insulation ring is the end of a piece of insulation tubing that sits between the Ring and Sleeve contacts along their entire length. If more of this tube is missing than just the end flange, the Ring and Sleeve may touch each other and cause problems.

However, the most likely cause of your symptoms is that the jack isn't straight.

An electronics store is unlikely to be able to replace just the insulation ring. Parts at that level aren't sold separately. They can sell you a replacement plug.

Answer (score 1):

These things are all pretty cheaply constructed.
Bending the plug sufficiently to break the insulation is likely also enough to have pulled the securing pin inside the barrel loose too.
End result is it's likely to be intermittent, even if you did manage to get it visibly straight… & as Hobbes also mentioned - you don't fix these things, you bin them & get a new one fitted.

New plug [even with screw-thread] under $£€ 5.

Cost of soldering by a pro… perhaps a fair bit more.

Comment: That's the problem. I haven't been able to find a jack with similar or better quality as the one I have originally, neither at local stores nor at online ones like Amazon, here in India!

Comment: These things don't really come in "quality levels" [& don't fall for the gold-plated marketing scams that make you think you're getting something worth more money]. The existing one is even at the cheaper end of that scale, it's just a moulded plug, unfixable.

Comment: I got a few which were like less than 50 cents so I am not able to easily trust those. Do you think it's possible to keep the "bendy" part while having the plug changed?

Comment: You can't keep the bendy part (strain relief) - you'll have to cut off the plug, then be able to strip ~8 mm of the insulation, which takes up most of the strain relief.

Comment: The only company I'd trust to supply a higher-than-most quality of 3.5 mm jack is Neutrik. (https://www.neutrik.com/en/product/ntp3rc)